# Recursion limit exceeded in non-recusrive procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, recursion, mariadb

I have a procedure which calls another procedure. They never call back to each other or call themselves, but I am getting an error response indicating that they are. The procedures are as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE grantPermission (perm VARCHAR(30), target VARCHAR(30), id VARCHAR(8), host VARCHAR(45), passwd VARCHAR(45))
  BEGIN 
    SET @setPermissionCmd = CONCAT('GRANT ', perm, ' ON ', target, ' TO ''', id, '''@''', host, ''' IDENTIFIED BY ''', passwd, ''';');
    PREPARE setPermissionStmt FROM @setPermissionCmd;
    EXECUTE setPermissionStmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE setPermissionStmt;
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
  END
```

and

```
CREATE PROCEDURE grantAdmin (id VARCHAR(8), host VARCHAR(45), passwd VARCHAR(45))
  BEGIN
    CALL grantPermission('EXECUTE', 'PROCEDURE createUser', id, host, passwd);
    CALL grantPermission('EXECUTE', 'PROCEDURE grantAdmin', id, host, passwd);
    CALL grantPermission('EXECUTE', 'PROCEDURE revokeAdmin', id, host, passwd);
    CALL grantPermission('INSERT,UPDATE', 'TaskType', id, host, passwd);
    CALL grantPermission('UPDATE', 'User', id, host, passwd);
    UPDATE User SET isAdmin=1 WHERE dbUser=id;
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
  END
```

When I call the second procedure, I get the following response:

```
MariaDB [pattsdb]> CALL grantAdmin('patts', '%', 'patts');
ERROR 1456 (HY000): Recursive limit 0 (as set by the max_sp_recursion_depth variable) was exceeded for routine grantAdmin
```

Why does it think my procedure is recursive? Just because the name is mentioned in the definition text?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add this to the beginning of the Stored Procedure:

```
SET max_sp_recursion_depth=255;
```

Comment: This works, but why did I need it in the first place? Just bad parsing practices?

Comment: Maybe this table has a trigger that runs this SP, which alters the table (and here's the recursion)

Comment: There are no triggers on the table. This is a very small database with 4 tables and a handful of SP that are no more than 10 lines each.

Comment: For starters, add this before the `Create Procedure` line