# Recursive limit 0 for stored procedure

Tags: c#, mysql

When I try to call stored procedure in c# . It is return:

> Recursive limit 0 (as set by the max_sp_recursion_depth variable) was exceeded for routine delete_medikalislem

delete_medikalislem procedure:

```
DELETE FROM medikal WHERE islem_id = p_id;
```

Stored Parameter:
Name: p_id, Type: VARCHAR, Length: 25

```
       using (MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
           {
             using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(mw.db_name+ ".delete_medikalislem", connect))
                 {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_id", mw.medikalislem[0]);
                    connect.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connect.Close();
                 }
            }
```

I using after delete trigger:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE tl_ integer default 0;
DECLARE usd_ integer default 0;
DECLARE eur_ integer default 0;
DECLARE gbp_ integer default 0;
DECLARE toplam_ integer default 0;

SELECT tl, usd, eur, gbp INTO tl_, usd_, eur_, gbp_ FROM medikalfirmalar WHERE isim = OLD.medikal_isim;
DELETE FROM medikal_caritahsilat WHERE islem_id = OLD.islem_id;
    IF (OLD.birim='TL') THEN
    SET toplam_= tl_ - OLD.tutar;
    UPDATE medikalfirmalar SET tl = toplam_ WHERE isim = OLD.medikal_isim;
    END IF;
    IF (OLD.birim='USD') THEN
    SET toplam_= usd_ - OLD.tutar;
    UPDATE medikalfirmalar SET usd = toplam_ WHERE isim = OLD.medikal_isim;
    END IF;
    IF (OLD.birim='EUR') THEN
    SET toplam_= eur_ - OLD.tutar;
    UPDATE medikalfirmalar SET eur = toplam_ WHERE isim = OLD.medikal_isim;
    END IF;
    IF (OLD.birim='GBP') THEN
    SET toplam_= gbp_ - OLD.tutar;
    UPDATE medikalfirmalar SET gbp = toplam_ WHERE isim = OLD.medikal_isim;
    END IF;
END
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: This may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111791/recursion-limit-exceeded-in-non-recusrive-procedure

Comment: I wonder if you're actually hitting a DB trigger (presumably a delete trigger) or similar

Comment: Are you calling the code more than once simultaneously from your code?  Are other users logged into the same database?

Answer (score 2):

It's just SQL complaining about recursiveness.

You have to explicitly tell it how many layers deep it can go with recursion.

Add this at the start of your procedure:

```
SET max_sp_recursion_depth=255;
```