# Recursive query Failing

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below table

```
TOPIC_NO    TOPIC_NAME  parent_no
54          Intro Main  0
56          LTCP        54
57          Intro Main  54
59          Intro       57
62          Link Demo   0
```

For a given topic no, I want to list down all the child, child of child..and so on. I am trying to frame the recursive query but running into "`The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion`."

Below is what I have done so far. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
WITH TEMP(TOPIC_NO) AS (
SELECT TOPIC_NO FROM EDUDB.TOPICS WHERE TOPIC_NO= 54
UNION ALL 
SELECT B.TOPIC_NO FROM EDUDB.TOPICS A, TEMP B
WHERE A.PARENT_NO = B.TOPIC_NO
AND A.PARENT_NO <> 0
)
SELECT * FROM TEMP;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursion limit exceeded in non-recusrive procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111791/recursion-limit-exceeded-in-non-recusrive-procedure)

Comment: The data is all thats in table right now. Its dummy table where I was trying the query. So i max hierarchy is 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a small mistake. See below:

```
WITH TEMP(TOPIC_NO) AS (
SELECT TOPIC_NO FROM EDUDB.TOPICS WHERE TOPIC_NO= 54
UNION ALL 
SELECT A.TOPIC_NO FROM EDUDB.TOPICS A, TEMP B -- here!
WHERE A.PARENT_NO = B.TOPIC_NO
AND A.PARENT_NO <> 0
)
SELECT * FROM TEMP;
```

You must get `A.TOPIC` instead of `B.TOPIC`.